# Mac OS X boots to question mark folder

Tags: boot, osx-leopard

I have a older MacBook running Mac OS 10.5.  I had not turned it on in a while but now it only boots to a light blue screen with a folder icon with a question mark on the folder. Any idea what this ?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the image does not show up but here it is .. http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2365/photoic.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [per this Apple article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2674), it means no bootable device has been found. You can try booting from your OS X DVD to see if you can detect the internal drive and run a repair against it using Disk Utility on the OS X DVD.